# I want a function in html5 to validate web address textfield

Tags: javascript, html

I want a function in html5 to validate web address textfield. This is the code i tried.
Its nt working.

```
function validateURL(textval) {
      var urlregex = new RegExp(
            "^(http|https|ftp)\://([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&amp;%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&amp;%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$");
      return urlregex.test(textval);
    }
```

Comment: Works fine for web addresses for me. What inputs do you want to validate?

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

Added the `pattern="https?://.+"`  attribute to input field, you have improved your url validation by demanding that all url's start with either **http://** or **https://**

```
<input type="url" name="url" required = "required" value="" pattern="https?://.+" >
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/Stk7s/

Comment: y does it gets cleared ? rather it should show a message what is missing in url.

Answer (score 0):

by default this will validate against the data given

```
     <input type="url" name="url" required = "required" value="" >
```